# IPMI : FATAL: Error inserting ipmi_si

Tags: linux, rhel6, ipmi, drive, modprobe

i have a problem with ipmi:

i've already install ipmitool, ipmi_devintf, ipmi_msghandler, but when i try to install ipmi_si i receive this message:

$ modprobe ipmi_si module
FATAL: Error inserting ipmi_si (/lib/modules/2.6.32-642.11.1.el6.x86_64/kernel/drivers/char/ipmi/ipmi_si.ko): Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)

this id a VM based on kvm with rhel 6.8.

Any tips ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

ipmi_si only works with real hardware. you can use something like virt-manager to see the VM console.

Comment: and how i resolve this ?   # ipmitool
Could not open device at /dev/ipmi0 or /dev/ipmi/0 or /dev/ipmidev/0: No such file or directory

Comment: again ipmi only works with real hardware.